# Irregular module detection/autocompletion in IPython

Tags: python, ipython

**(Check edit for better explanation)**

*(Screenshot is of the built-in python console in pycharm which uses ipython. Same problem exists if I use ipython separately as well.
[image]
In the IPython console, if I type `from gi.repository import` and press tab to see the available options, I don't see any of these modules (Glib, RB, Gtk, Gio etc.). But if I execute `from gi.repository import RB` or `Gtk` etc, it works! Even though it shouldn't according to my autocomplete list.
 Then if I type `from gi.repository import` and press tab, I see the module I imported previously. Same with any other module from the list.
Why is this happening? It's causing wrongly reported errors in PyCharm (as you can see in the screenshot).*

EDIT: To illustrate the problem better:

See what I mean? At first it showed only `RB` and `absolute_import` as choices. STILL I was able to import `Gtk`. After that it showed a couple of more options. Still isn't a complete list of modules.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add that directory as "source" content root.

http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/configuring-content-roots.html

The pycharm autosuggest will start showing the suggestions.

Comment: But this problem is not specific to Pycharm. It happens with pure ipython as well. I just put a screenshot of pycharm because it utilizes ipython and that's how I discovered the problem.

Answer (score 0):

reconstruct list of available modules : `%rehashx` cf `%rehashx?`, last paragraph.

```
Update the alias table with all executable files in $PATH.

This version explicitly checks that every entry in $PATH is a file
with execute access (os.X_OK), so it is much slower than %rehash.

Under Windows, it checks executability as a match against a
'|'-separated string of extensions, stored in the IPython config
variable win_exec_ext.  This defaults to 'exe|com|bat'.

This function also resets the root module cache of module completer,
used on slow filesystems.
```

Comment: Nope it doesn't seem to fix anything. Do check the edit for a better explanation of the problem.